# Why does the default Insert/edit link function in Visual mode in posts or pages produce full urls?

Tags: pages, description

Situation:
I'm using the default description field on a page in visual mode. I'm trying to link the words "news page" to the my news page. I pick the News page from the content list that is offered to me in the Insert/edit pop-up window.
The url field is filled with:

> http://belgianstrokecouncil.be/news/

(generates a full url in the top url field of the pop-up window)

, while generating the address link

> /news/

would make more sense. Hardcoded links make life difficult after domain name changes.

Why does the default Insert/edit link function in Visual mode in posts or pages make you use the full URL instead of just using the last part of the address?

I can off course switch to Text mode and simply edit the url to be /news/, but that would defeat the purpose of using an easy insert/edit url function.

Maybe it's a setting, 
maybe there's a plugin, 
maybe I'm doing it wrong. The last one being more likely. :)

Kind regards,

Comment: There's some discussion of why relative URLs are "considered harmful" here -- [Why relative URLs should be forbidden](https://yoast.com/relative-urls-issues/). It touches on WP's preference for generating full URLs as well as the fact that it tries to create a `301 Redirect` for any relative URLs that it discovers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your forgetting the Pages are stored in the Database.  The database does not use relative linking.  You can control the output by Activating PrettyPermalinks.  For moving a domain you must use a Database Backup/Restore Plugin and modify wp-config.php should the database name change